# How to inject UriInfo object into non-resource classes

Tags: java, jersey-2.0

In process of modifying my project code I've found out that I have no chance to insert UriInfo object into resource class (using @Context annotation)
Unfortunately I cannot change method or constructors signatures to retrieve uriinfo in resource in pass it to service class.

Is there any option to insert UriInfo into usual class (not jax-rs)?
Maybe there is some option to say Jersey scan not only resource classes but custom ones?
**EDIT:**

Here is some code example

```
@Path("path")
public class JerseyResource {
   @Get
   public Responce executeMethod(@QueryParam Criteria criteria, @QueryParam ObjType type) {
        return RestUtils.chooseServiceByType(type).process(criteria);
   }
}
```

**RestUtils.chooseServiceByType(type)** can return ~15 different instances.
And only for 1 instance (i.e. **Type2LogicProcessorServiceImpl**) i need access to **uriInfo** object in **process(criteria)** method

Thank you,
Dima

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to bind that class as a service in Jersey's DI framework, [HK2](https://hk2.java.net/). Jersey uses HK2 for most its injection, including `@Context` injections. Since `@Context` is tied to the DI, is your service is bound to the DI, you can accept `@Context` injections in your services.

For example, if you have this `Service` class

```
public class Service {
    
    @Context 
    UriInfo uriInfo;
    
    public String getUri() {
        return uriInfo.getRequestUri().toASCIIString();
    }
}
```

Then you need to bind it something like

```
public class Binder extends AbstractBinder {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(Service.class).to(Service.class);
    }
}
```

Then register the binder with Jersey. In a `ResourceConfig` you can do

```
public class AppConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public AppConfig() {
        register(new Binder());
    }
}
```

If you are using web.xml, then there is no way to directly register the binder. You will need to use a [`Feature`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Feature.html) and let the feature be discovered. There you can register the binder.

```
@Provider
public class BinderFeature implements Feature {
    @Override
    public boolean configure(FeatureContext ctx) {
        ctx.register(new Binder());
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then you can inject the `Service` into your resource class

```
@Path("uri")
public class UriResource {
    
    @Inject
    Service service;
    
    @GET
    public String get() {
        return service.getUri();
    }
}
```

**For more Info:**

- [Custom Injection and Lifecycle Management](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Feature.html) from Jersey docs.
- The HK2 link above for more info on working directly with HK2

---

#### UPDATE

Have a look at the following test. It can all be run with a single test dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

What I do is use an HK2 `Factory` to inject the query param `ObjType`, and get the `Service` (which is now just an interface super type). If it's the type that need the `UriInfo`, I explicitly inject it with the `ServiceLocator`. The factory and the locator are probably new concepts for you, so I would go through the two above documentation links I provided, if you want to learn more.

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;

import org.glassfish.hk2.api.Factory;
import org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocator;
import org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder;
import org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;

import org.junit.Test;
import static junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals;

public class UriInfoTest extends JerseyTest {
    
    public static interface Service {
        String getUri();
    }
    
    public static class ServiceOne implements Service {
        
        @Context 
        UriInfo uriInfo;
        
        @Override
        public String getUri() {
            return uriInfo.getRequestUri().toASCIIString();
        }
    }
    
    public static class ServiceTwo implements Service {
        @Override
        public String getUri() {
            return "Blah";
        }
    }
    
    public static class ObjType {
        String param;
        public ObjType(String param) {
            this.param = param;
        }
    }
    
    static class RestUtils {
        static Service getServiceByType(ObjType type) {
            switch (type.param) {
                case "one": return new ServiceOne();
                case "two": return new ServiceTwo();
                default: return new ServiceOne();
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static class ServiceFactory implements Factory<Service> {
        
        @QueryParam("type")
        ObjType type;
        
        @Inject
        ServiceLocator locator;

        @Override
        public Service provide() {
            Service service = RestUtils.getServiceByType(type);
            if (service instanceof ServiceOne) {
                locator.inject(service);
            }
            return service;
        }

        @Override
        public void dispose(Service t) {}     
    }
    
    public static class Binder extends AbstractBinder {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bindFactory(ServiceFactory.class).to(Service.class);
        }
    }
    
    @Path("uri")
    public static class UriResource {
        
        @Inject
        Service service;
        
        @GET
        public String get() {
            return service.getUri();
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public ResourceConfig configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(UriResource.class)
                .register(new Binder())
                .register(new LoggingFilter(Logger.getAnonymousLogger(), true));
    }
    
    @Test
    public void doit() {
        Response response = target("uri").queryParam("type", "one").request().get();
        assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());
        String message = response.readEntity(String.class);
        assertEquals("http://localhost:9998/uri?type=one", message);
        response.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @peeskillet. Let me try this.
I'll update with results

Comment: So I still need to inject MyService in resource to be able to get not empty UrlInfo?

Comment: Where else do you plan on using it?

Comment: Actually, i don't need myservice in resource class. There is a stack of method calls that eventually brings execution point to MyService.doLogic() method. And inside this method I need UriInfo object

Comment: Where does this stack of calls originate from? I imagine it's from the resource class, or somewhere in the Jersey application right? You might want to use injection throughout the call stack. I don't know your exact architecture, so I don't know if I can be of more help.

Comment: Ok. Let me describe with some details.
I have Resource that is used for many client rest calls.
When new call comes to rest resource there is little bit strange logic to decide what service will be executed (I have ~ 15 service to choose). And only in one of these 15 (let it be MyService) I need UriInfo object.
So the main my problem is t hat I cannot change logic for this **decider** logic and cannot pass uriinfo to all services....

Comment: Doesn't help much. Probably best to show some actual code.

Comment: Edit your original question with some real code example that demonstrates the problem you described in your comment

Comment: I've edited.
Anyway I realy appreciate your help. You at least give me some point to dive into :)
Thank you!

Comment: Thank you one more time! I think I got the idea

Comment: @peeskillet, can you provide specific links to documentation describing support for injecting `@Context` into HK2 services? Also, does HK2 support this for any JAX-RS container, or only with Jersey?

Comment: @shelley There's the [Jersey docs](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/ioc.html), and the [HK2 docs](https://hk2.java.net/2.4.0-b07/). You can also look through some of [my HK2 posts](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a2587435%20[hk2]). I think there are some that are really informative. And no, HK2 is specific to the Jersey implementation.